# Load Google web fonts script link asynchronously

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fonts, google-webfonts

I'm trying to increase my website performance by doing some tweaks, and i have found the google web fonts scripts to load fonts 
asynchronously, the problem is that the fonts loads 
asynchronously but not the script src link so i just moved the problem with css to js.

**My actual code is that:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.5.18/webfont.js"></script>
<script>
   WebFont.load({
      google: {
        families: ['Oswald:400,300', 'Material+Icons']]
      }
});
```

I've tried to use async and defer but on the script src but it didn't work (it eliminated the page block render but the fonts didn't loaded like the other scripts do with async).

**So what's the best way to remove the script src link?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This.

```
<script>
   WebFontConfig = {
        google: { families: ['Oswald:400,300', 'Material+Icons'] }
   };

   (function(d) {
        var wf = d.createElement('script'), s = d.scripts[0];
        wf.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.6.26/webfont.js';
        wf.async = true;
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
   })(document);
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Here ya go, include this in the body, right before `</body>` and not the head tag

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Noto+Serif" rel="stylesheet" lazyload>`

This makes the font load ***after*** everything above it.

But instead of Noto Serif, use Oswald font in your case.

Answered originally by user "Paddy" here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40624546/6283055

Comment: As @soren121 mentioned in the comment of the same answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40624546/6283055 
lazyload attribute isn't supported in the vast majority of browsers - https://caniuse.com/#feat=lazyload